# Add a date picker in jframe?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, datepicker, jframe

I would like to add a Datepicker in Jframe? Is that possible?, do you reccomend any specific library with a date picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find a Swing library which offers such a date picker, it will most likely by a `JComponent` which can be added to a `JFrame` (if this would not be the case, no Swing developer in his right mind would want to use the library).

I have no personal experience with the `JXDatePicker` from the SwingX project, but every one of the components from SwingX I already tried have a decent API and a nice behavior, so I dare recommending the `JXDatePicker`.

Answer (score 1):

May be [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html). It's open source, supports LaF, localized. Here is its online [demo](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/demo.html).

You may also consider [DateSpinner](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/spinner/DateSpinner.html). It is part of [JIDE's open source layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm). JIDE also offers `DateChooserPanel` but it is part of Grids library, which is not free.